# Joomla - Force File Download / CSV Export

Tags: php, csv, joomla

I'm in need of help... this is my first time asking a question in SO, so please be kind :)

I'm trying to force-download a file from php, so when the user hits a certain button, he gets a file download. The file is a csv (email, username) of all registered users.

I decided to add this button to the admin > users screen, as you can see in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6otwA.png)[image].

So I added the following code to the *addToolbar* function in administrator/components/com_users/views/users/view.html.php:

```
JToolBarHelper::custom('users.export', 'export.png', 'export_f2.png', 'Exportar', false);
```

This button is mapped to the following function in the com_users\controller\users.php controller:

```
public function exportAllUsers() {
    ob_end_clean();
    $app = JFactory::getApplication();

    header("Content-type: text/csv");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=ideary_users.csv");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");

    echo "email,name\n";

    $model = $this->getModel("Users");
    $users = $model->getAllUsers();

    foreach ($users as $user) {
        echo $user->email . ", " . ucwords(trim($user->name)) . "\r\n";
    }

    $app->close();

}
```

Now, **this is actually working perfectly fine**.

**The issue here is** that after I download a file, if I hit any button in the admin that causes a POST, instead of it performing the action it should, it just downloads the file over again!
For example:

- I hit the "Export" button
- "users.csv" downloads
- Then, I hit the "search" button
- "users.csv" downloads... what the hell?

I'm guessing that when I hit the export button, a JS gets called and sets a form's *action* attribute to an URL... and expects a response or something, and then other button's are prevented from re-setting the form's action attribute. I can't think of any real solution for this, but I'd rather avoid hacks if possible.

So, what would be the standard, elegant solution that joomla offers in this case?

Comment: Did you create a plug-in to add the button and method or have you hacked the core files? If you've hacked the core what other changes have you made to get it to work up to this point?

Comment: Hey! Thanks for editing my question!

What do you mean by "hacking the core files"? I did modify the files I mentioned in the question, which I believe are core jooomla files, part of the administrator/users screen. But I didn't really modify anything, just added the new function.

For the button, I'm just calling JToolBarHelper::custom, JToolBarHelper was already there. 

But really the code I uploaded is all there is to it, there's just one line of code that I didn't include, the mapping of the task to the function, but that's standard.

Comment: Oh sorry, I missed that line, my bad. I'm guessing the line you didn't add was to register the call with the controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the bit you're missing is the Javascript that handles toolbar buttons, if you're just doing default actions New/Delete/Publish/Unpublish etc you don't need to add anything.

However, for custom buttons you usually have to override the default behaviour (which sets some hidden form values as they expect a page to be returned, causing a refresh and never hitting the problem you've encountered).

So normally a button relies on the `submitbutton()` from `includes/js/joomla.javascript.js`

```javascript
function submitbutton(pressbutton) {
  submitform(pressbutton);
}
```

Which amongst other things sets the value of the `task` input field of the `#adminForm` to the buttons task, i.e. in your case `user.export`

You will need to add some Javascript to `com_users/views/users/tmpl/default.php` to call your method via `window.location` or similar.

As you don't want the default behaviour you need to create your own override for `submitbutton()` something like this:

```javascript
function submitbutton(pressbutton) {
    // Check if it's your button
    if(pressbutton == 'users.export') {
        // Call your method with something like this:
        window.location = 'index.php?option=com_users&task=users.export'
        // That should be it, this way you don't set the task value for future clicks
    } else {
      // If not follow the normal path
      document.adminForm.task.value=pressbutton;
      submitform(pressbutton);
    }
}
```

You can find more [here](http://docs.joomla.org/J1.5%3aHow_to_create_a_custom_button) in the archived section of the [Joomla Doc's website.](http://docs.joomla.org/)

Answer (score 1):

**Add this code to your view controller**

```
function export(){

    ob_end_clean();
    $app = JFactory::getApplication();

    header("Content-type: text/csv");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=slic_student.csv");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");

    echo "ID,School Name,Student Name,Student No\n";

    $model = $this->getModel("students");
    $users = $model->export_query();

    foreach ($users as $user) {
        echo $user->student_id . ", " . ucwords(trim($user->school_name)) . ", " . ucwords(trim($user->student_name)) . ", " . ucwords(trim($user->student_no)) . "\r\n";
    }
    $app->close();
}
```

**Add this to the view.html.php**

```
  JToolBarHelper::custom('students.export','','', 'CSV Export', false);
```